# pytorch gather failed with sparse_grad=True

Tags: python, pytorch, backpropagation

With even very simple example, `backward()` cannot work if `sparse_grad=True`, please see the error below.

Is this error expected, or I'm using `gather` in a wrong way?

```py
In [1]: import torch as th

In [2]: x = th.rand((3,3), requires_grad=True)

# sparse_grad = False, the backward could work as expetecd
In [3]: th.gather(x @ x, 1, th.LongTensor([[0], [1]]), sparse_grad=False).sum().backward()

# sparse_grad = True, backward CANNOT work
In [4]: th.gather(x @ x, 1, th.LongTensor([[0], [1]]), sparse_grad=True).sum().backward()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 th.gather(x @ x, 1, th.LongTensor([[0], [1]]), sparse_grad=True).sum().backward()

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs)
    305                 create_graph=create_graph,
    306                 inputs=inputs)
--> 307         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
    308
    309     def register_hook(self, hook):

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
    152         retain_graph = create_graph
    153
--> 154     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
    155         tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs,
    156         allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # allow_unreachable flag

RuntimeError: sparse tensors do not have strides
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `torch.gather` does not support sparse operators:

```py
torch.gather(x, 1, torch.LongTensor([[0], [1]]).to_sparse())
```

Results with:

> ```
> NotImplementedError: Could not run 'aten::gather.out' with arguments from the 'SparseCPU' backend.
> ```

I think you should open an issue or a feature request on [pytorch's github](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature-request.yml).

Comment: The code example in your answer is interesting, my code didn't use a sparse `LongTensor` as index, why did you do that?

Comment: @avocado I explicitly pushed it to use sparse representation to get a meaningful error message. I was also hoping that if the index tensor was explicitly sparse, `gather` would not expect a "dense" grad tensor. At the moment, the error message **you** got is not very meaningful, the one I got suggests we stumbled upon a feature that needs to be implemented...

Comment: Thanks for this! BTW, in my code I'm using `gather` just as documented in pytorch's website, and it doesn't work, so I think this should be a bug?

Comment: It's indeed a problem involving matmul and sparse gradient, response from pytorch maintainers said this is more like a new feature needed. Answer accepted, thanks.

Comment: @avocado thanks. sorry cannot help more. However, pytorch is an open source project - feel free to contribute this feature!

Answer (score 0):

torch.gather does support sparse operation hence you can set the key argument sparse_grad=True. See documentation: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html

However, if you do use sparse gradients, the number of operations you can use, decreases. Some operations are simply not defined for a sparse gradient, others not implemented.

From your error, I think you use a kernel somewhere or a similar operation that requires you to set a stride. That stride requires a full gradient as it is defined for a full gradient. Since you only have a sparse gradient, the stride tries to take gradients as input that have not been computed in the sparse operation.

If you want to get your code to work with sparse gradient, you must restrict the loss computation to the sparse gradient. Don't use strides or anything else that requires a full gradient.